# How to store output of a shell command in nodejs and use it for other operation

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get a helm release name via executing below code in nodejs

and then wanted to delete that release

```
var sys = require('sys')
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

output = spawn('helm',['list', '-q', '--namespace', 'd35nb8']);

release = output.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                var test = process.stdout.write(data.toString());
                process.stdout.write(data.toString()) 
                spawn('helm',['delete', test]);

});
```

code here is able to get the helm release name but could not delete the release

code outputs as

```
oot@5a857d30a4c1:/opt/api# nodejs test2.js
inside moving further
(node:2272) [DEP0025] DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
kilted-markhor
kilted-markhor
```

how could I achieve this logic here in nodejs

Comment: Have you tried `spawn('helm',['delete', data.toString()]);`?

Comment: That did not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `spawn` is needed for more sophisticated child process management. For the described use case I would suggest using simple `exec`:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('helm list -q --namespace d35nb8'], (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('helm list failed', err);
    } else {
        const releases = stdout.split('\n');  // or whatever is the separator
        for (const r of releases) {
            console.log('deleting release', r);
            exec('helm delete ' + r, (err2) => {
                if (err2) {
                    console.log('helm delete failed', err2);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```